# Maintaining a selected item from a colelction of items in Entity Framework (Code First)

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

This is my first question so hope

Basically given two classes like the following:

```
public class Teacher
{
    public virtual Subject SelectedSubject { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Subject> Subject { get; set; }
}

public class Subject
{
    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Ideally, I am trying to represent the fact that a teacher can have multiple subjects and is currently teaching a specific one.

The problem is despite setting the specific one (SelectedSubject), it always remains null. The virtual collection "subjects" loads fine though.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

This seemed to work:

```
public class Teacher
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }

    public virtual Subject SelectedSubject { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Subject> Subjects { get; set; }
}

public class Subject
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
}
```

and also:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
     modelBuilder.Entity<Teacher>().HasMany(t => t.Subjects);
}
```